# freeradius получить mac клиента

Tags: python, django, freeradius

Суть проблемы, нужно как то получать mac клиента дабы привязываться к нему и отсеивать неугодных. freeradius и за NAS выступает mikrotik. При попытке логина шлется запрос на радиус сервер и оттуда можно получить mac из Calling-Station-Id, но вот проблема, страничка регистрации на сервере, т.е. она от NAS никак не получает данные. Есть мысль на кнопке регистрации повесить что нить что будет слать запрос авторизации и я получу заветный Calling-Station-Id но какой код вставить в страничку логина микротика пока что мыслей нет. Система авторизации крутится на django + postgresql. А как вы получаете  mac клиента?

Comment: страница регистрации на сервере доступна до авторизации на freeradius?

Comment: вроде того, сервер добавлен в walled garden. Если вручную прописать адрес странички регистрации - тоже откроет

Comment: из внутренней сети узнаем IP, по IP узнаем mac. Из внешней способов не знаю нормальных, не нормальные запустить java или activex компонент на компьютере пользователя и им передать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Микротик оказывается может многое, в том числе передавать мак и прочее.
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/HotSpot_external_login_page

и никаких костылей в виде выдрать мак по айпи или фэйковую авторизацию.